# pymongo MongoClient end_request() will not terminate cursor

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i have a question about pymongo connection pool  - MongoClient

how is it possible that the cursor ("results" in the following example) is retrieving the documents, even after the connection was returned to the connection pool by end_request() statement

```
mongo_connection_pool = MongoClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=27017)
db_connection = mongo_connection_pool["db_name"]
collection = db_connection["collection"]
results = collection.find()
db_connection.end_request()

for result in results:
    print result
```

is there something that i'm missing?

cheers

Comment: What version of PyMongo are you using? The current [docs](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html) don't mention an `end_request` method and doing something similar to what you have results in an error on my end.

Comment: i'm using 2.8  
http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#module-pymongo.mongo_client

Comment: Well, the method you've mentioned [there](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.end_request) is on the client (what you are calling the connection pool) and not the database. In any case it's deprecated at version 2.8. And based on the description, it shouldn't do anything since you never called `start_request`.

Answer (score 4):

In PyMongo 2.x [MongoClient.start_request](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.start_request) is used to pin a socket from the connection pool to an application thread. [MongoClient.end_request](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.end_request) removes that mapping (if it exists).

This has no impact on iterating a cursor. For each OP_GET_MORE operation the driver has to execute it will get a socket out of the pool. If you are in a "request" it will use the request socket for the current thread. If not, it will use any available socket. [You can read more about requests here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.7.2/examples/requests.html). Note that "requests" [no longer exist in PyMongo 3.0](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/examples/requests.html).

If you want to "terminate" a cursor you can del the cursor object, or call [cursor.close()](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.close)

Comment: start_request an end_request are deprecated. how can i explicitly mention in the code, that the connection was returned to the pool  (is cursor.close() the proper way? is it necessary at all? )?

Comment: There is no way to explicitly check out or return a socket to the pool. PyMongo handles this automatically. When you execute some operation (insert, update, find, command, etc.) PyMongo checks a socket out of the pool, uses it to execute the operation, then immediately returns it to the pool. Calling Cursor.close() ensures that the server side cursor is closed. It has nothing to do with connections or pooling.